# BooleanRenderer of Qooxdoo framework

Tags: qooxdoo, cellrenderer

Is it possible to set some styles like width and height to the Boolean cell renderer ??

```
var BooleanRenderer = new qx.ui.table.cellrenderer.Boolean();
```

Answer (score 1):

You can define your own renderer that will allow you to have complete control of the presentation; the `BooleanRenderer` class is fairly straightforward, and would be a good place to start.